# Eliminating the biggest overlapping spheres

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a program which tries to eliminate those spheres that overlaps with other smaller. First I define a structure of spheres (x,y,z,r), then I define a vector of spheres and I order them in decreasing order. Finally, I check in two spheres overlaps, and if they do I only eliminate the biggest one. However, the code doesn't seem to work properly. I've been told I have to obtain spheres with bigger radii than the ones I obtain, but I don't know what can be wrong in the code.

The code is the following:

```
std::vector<double> xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, r;

struct sphere { double X,Y,Z,R; };
std::vector<sphere> Spheres;

inline constexpr bool overlap(sphere const&a, sphere const&b) noexcept
{ return square(a.X-b.X)+square(a.Y-b.Y)+square(a.Z-b.Z) < square(a.R+b.R); }


void new_algorithm(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y, const std::vector<double>& z, const std::vector<double>& r, std::vector<double>& overlaps)
{
    ofstream escribir;

    std::vector<sphere> S;
    S.reserve(r.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); i++)
    {
        S.push_back(sphere{x[i],y[i],z[i],r[i]});
    }
    
    //Sort descending R
    std::sort(S.begin(), S.end(), [](sphere const&a, sphere const&b) { return a.R > b.R; });

    // Clear overlaps 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < S.size(); i++)
    {   
        overlaps[i]=0;
    }
        
    for(size_t i=0; i<S.size(); ++i) 
    {
        for(size_t j=i+1; j<S.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (overlap(S[i], S[j]))
            {
                overlaps[i] = 1;
            }
            if(overlaps[i]==1) break;
        }
    }

    escribir.open("nonoverlapping.txt");
    escribir << "x" << "\t" << "y" << "\t" << "z" << "\t" << "r" << "\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i != r.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (overlaps[i] == 0)
        {
            escribir << S[i].X << "\t" << S[i].Y << "\t" << S[i].Z << "\t" << S[i].R << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "Non-overlapping written into a file..." << "\n";

   
}

int main()
{
    ifstream leer1;
    int i, j;
    vector<double> xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, r, d, overlaps;
    double a, b, c, aux, contador;
    double t0, t1;

    leer1.open("centrosmini.txt");
    while (!leer1.eof())
    {
            leer1 >> a;
            leer1 >> b;
            leer1 >> c;
            leer1 >> aux;
            xcentro.push_back(a);
            ycentro.push_back(b);
            zcentro.push_back(c);
            r.push_back(aux);
    }
    leer1.close();
    cout << "Data read..." << "\n";
    cout << xcentro.size() << "\n";

    new_algorithm(xcentro,ycentro,zcentro,r,overlaps);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the code doesn't seem to work properly", what do you mean? For which cases does it not work? And what is it doing instead? Or is it crashing? ...?

Comment: @Dominique what i mean is what i said, that I should get bigger radios (vector r) than I do

Answer (score 1):

The vector `overlaps` is never resized, so it has length zero, but you are writing to it anyway. This causes the program to crash immediately on my system.

Another issue is that you forget to check the last sphere when printing the results.

Also, there is the issue that after reading the last line, `leer1.eof()` is still `false`. Only after trying to read past the end of the file will `eof()` be set. The correct way to read in the spheres is:

```
while (true) {
    leer1 >> a >> b >> c >> aux;
    if (!leer1) {
        // Either the end of the file was reached,
        // or some error occured while reading the file.
        break;
    }
    xcentro.push_back(a);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think any of these problems are causing my program to work improperly. I reserve a size for every single vector in int main. In addition, I don't get any crash or anything like that, and I've checked the way of reading it and it reads all the vectors. My problem is that I eliminate spheres which I shouldn't eliminate, as I should get bigger spheres (bigger radii)

Comment: I don't see any call to `resize()` or `reserve()` for `overlaps` in the code you posted, and you are not using `push_back()` on it either. It helps if you would show us an example input that causes your program to generate the wrong output, along with the expected output.

Comment: you're right, I forgot to add that part to the code. I don't know here to put the input and the output. In input is a catalogue of galaxies (uchuu) and the output is the non overlapping spheres, as explained before. The wrong thing with the output is that I obtain small spheres and I should obtain bigger ones

Comment: It's hard for us to help you if you leave out relevant parts of the code and don't give an example of input and expected output. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: that was the only thing left. Taking into account that I've written the .reserve() stuff, now it's everything completed

Answer (score 0):

Just a remark on your overlap function. What you basically are doing, is the following:

```
(a.X-b.X)^2 + (a.Y-b.Y)^2 + (a.Z-b.Z)^2 <= (a.R+b.R)^2
```

This is correct, but in order to execute it, it does four floating point multiplications for every circle.

You can optimise this:

```
if ((ABS(a.X - b.X) > a.R + b.R) ||
    (ABS(a.Y - b.Y) > a.R + b.R) ||
    (ABS(a.Z - b.Z) > a.R + b.R))
  return no_overlap
else <do your original calculation>
```

In most cases, you just will need to do some subtractions, instead of multiplications, which might heavily improve your performance.

Comment: This may or may not improve performance, depending on how well the branches can be predicted. Note that OP's overlap function can be compiled to [quite efficient machine code](https://godbolt.org/z/337EbGa7f) on recent processors, making use of instructions like [VFMADD213SD](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vfmadd132sd:vfmadd213sd:vfmadd231sd) that can multiply and add whole SIMD vectors in one go.